# WinCVS commit corrupt word files

Tags: cvs, configurationmanager, wincvs

I commit a MS word file in CVS Server using WinCVS. I selected the add option as Text. whether it should be added as binary format. Now I checked out my files. when i tried to open those files. it says that these files are corrupted and can not open. is there any way to change the format of these files located in CVS-Server or retrieve those file as i have no backup on my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

MS Word files are binary files, so it's very possible that CVS corrupted them when adding to the repository.

I'm not familiar with WinCVS but would recommend looking for an option which allows the file type to be changed from "text" to "binary". If you can't find such option then you might try removing the files and then adding them again as binaries (I've seen this reported as working for WinCVS in this thread: http://dbaspot.com/forums/configuration-management/193699-binarys-text.html).

(Alternatively, if you're comfortable using CVS from the command line/DOS prompt then you could use CVS directly: move to the folder with the checked-out files and then do:

```
cvs admin -kb [file_name]
```

for each of the problem files.)